# Line 24: XML Syntax error. On console.exe is running

Tags: c#

I have a .net console app which is written in C#, this is supposed to be setup in a task scheduler(as job), I have setup the task with all the requirements(action, triggers, conditions and settings). However when I try to run the job I see an error that reads **The application has failed because of its side-by-side configuration**, when check the event logs I see the error that reads **Invalid Xml syntax**

Parsing Application Config File D:\Applications\XXXXXX\XXXXXXX.exe.Config.
    ERROR: Line 24: XML Syntax error.
`<add key="xxx" value="xxxx">`

I have then since open the config file with notepad++, set the language to xml to see there is anything amiss in the file but there is nothing wrong in as far as I can see

Here is a more detailed config part(in case some asks for it)

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="PXSSynductisContext"
            connectionString="Data Source=CD-SQL-ESRV.BGC.NET;5
         Initial Catalog=dbBCPor;
         User Id=UserBcPorDev;
         Password=@?7TEaSEr6;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="PXSSynductisContext" connectionString="Data Source=########; Initial Catalog=Db_ITT; User Id=User;Password=*******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="PXSSynductisContext" connectionString="Data Source=########;Initial Catalog=DbBcPor;integrated security=False;user id=UserBcPor;password=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="uploadfilepath" value="http://dersq1.web.bc:22021/file-upload/file/upload"/>
    <add key="DownloadFilePath" value="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Shared\\test"/>
    <add key="UNAME" value="API-PROXIMUS-1@mailinator.com"/>
    <add key="PASSWRD" value="$S$DdSMbLQubAALij9tusbCYUHU0IkdYN4EzYLSlJuVTc8zO8Ex5I/t"/>
<add key="BaseURL" value="https://wwwtest.aansluitingen.be/api/v1/status"/>
    <add key="ORESUNAME" value="prox-dev@cmhores.onmicrosoft.com"/>
<add key="PWD" value="Proximus103027"/>
<add key="BaseURL" value="https://ores-cmhapi-dev.azurewebsites.net/"/>
<add key="LASTNAME" value="Synergie Wallonie"/>
<add key="FIRSTNAME" value="Prox"/>
<add key="PHONE" value="081428300"/>
<add key="EMAIL" value="Prox-syne-Wall@prox.com"/>
<add key="POSTALCODE" value="6001"/>
<add key="LOCALITY" value="Marcinelle"/>
<add key="STREET" value="avenue Eugène Mascaux 223"/>
<add key="NBSUPPLYPOINTS" value="1"/>
<add key="JOINTINGSERVICE" value=""/>
<add key="POWALCOORGANIZATIONID" value="Prox CUO PROV"/>
<add key="WebProxy" value="appproxy.cfg.net:8080"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

`

What syntax error am  I having here exactly?

Comment: `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` Perhaps the fact you've got the same key twice? You've also shown the first 9 lines of the config and the error is on line 24.

Comment: What is on line 24?

Comment: even after removing it i am still facing the issue.
just a string value

Comment: there is no xml closing tag `/` in the line 24 I suppose: `<add key="xxx" value="xxxx">`. It should be like `<add key="xxx" value="xxxx" />`

Comment: @oleksa i have added the actual code

Comment: Please open the xml document in the xml editor (VisualStudio) to check the syntax. It looks like you have an syntax error but complete document must be checked.

Comment: When dealing with those kind of error messages it's always advisable to check the lines BEFORE the actual line number from the error message. Often times the error occurs before, but the error is thrown a few lines later, because there the syntax error becomes apparent.

Comment: @oleksa add the whole xml can you please check

Comment: @waka whole xml is updated

Comment: there is extra closing tag in the last line: `</configuration>/> ` it must be like `</configuration>`

Comment: oleksa is right, this xml does not pass a validation at https://www.xmlvalidation.com - it points out that exact error

Comment: @oleksa    it happened while pasting in question

Comment: @Veverke  while replacing old code it happened. using xml validator didnt find any issue.

Comment: I understand you can locally run the program (as opposed to as a scheduled task) without problems - i.e., without xml parsing errors, am I correct ?

Comment: Probably shouldn't be pasting your usernames and passwords in the question...

Comment: @Veverke 
yes while running in code it is working fine. but when scheduled in task scheduler it is gving error

Comment: @Thewads those values are not accurate. just for question prepared a sample and tested it still getting error so pasted in question

Comment: @vamsi: your app config might be missing/the path must be wrong while running as scheduled task. Make sure you read from a fixed path and that the file is there, regardless of debug/scheduled task.